# Her parents gave away the prizes to our school (school's?) children

Tags: apostrophe

Is it all right to say :

> Her parents gave away the prizes to our school children.

Or I need to add apostrophe with school ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "school children" or "schoolchildren", but this only makes sense if you personally work at, or own, the school:

> Her parents gave away the prizes to our **schoolchildren**.

If instead by "our school" means "the school which you or your children attend" and not where you work, then you should use the possessive:

> Her parents gave away the prizes to our **school's** children.